# Hibernate : How to change the auto generated foreign key column name from lowercase to uppercase

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, h2

I am migrating old spring boot application to latest spring boot 2.3.0

Migration happens successfully, however, when I try to connect the application to the existing database, it is not able to identify autogenerated foreign key columns due to uppercase and lowercase issue.

the foreign key column name in the older version had upper case letters as shown below. here, FLAGCATEGORY_FLAGCATEGORYID is the foreign key column name which is autogenerated by hibernate

[image]

When I use the new spring boot version with hibernate 5, it is generating lowercase foreign key column names. Due to this difference, the application can not be started with the older database. Could anybody suggest me what should I  do to resolve this without changing the database schema?
[image]

here is how the new foreign key table name looks like. foreign key column name now has lowercase letters
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use your own column names instead of the auto-generated ones, try adding this annotation on your flagCategory getter:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "FLAGCATEGORY_FLAGCATEGORYID")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Actually I knew this method. I wanted an answer which allow me to configure hibernate to use lowercase when it is automatically generating those foreign key column names in uppercase without me having to explicitly tell which case it needs to use. If I use this method, I have to go and change 100+  model classes.

Answer (score 1):

`Hibernate` resolves a logical name to a physical name using [`PhysicalNamingStrategy`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/javadocs/org/hibernate/boot/model/naming/PhysicalNamingStrategy.html) contract. The default implementation is to simply use the logical name as the physical name.

You can define a custom implementation:

```java
public class FooPhysicalNamingStrategy implements PhysicalNamingStrategy {

    // Changing the column names to upper case
    @Override
    public Identifier toPhysicalColumnName(Identifier identifier,
                                           JdbcEnvironment jdbcEnvironment) {
        
        return jdbcEnvironment
                .getIdentifierHelper()
                .toIdentifier(identifier.getText().toUpperCase(), identifier.isQuoted());
    }

    // Keeping as it is
    @Override
    public Identifier toPhysicalSchemaName(Identifier identifier, 
                                           JdbcEnvironment jdbcEnvironment) {
        
        return identifier;
    }

    // Other overridden methods    
}
```

And set `hibernate.physical_naming_strategy` setting to the [FQN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_name) of the class or to reference the class.

For example, add the following property to your `persistence-unit` in `persistence.xml`:

```xml
<property name="hibernate.physical_naming_strategy" value="foo.bar.FooPhysicalNamingStrategy"/>
```

#### NOTE

**JPA Introspection:**

From [Hibernate User Guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#PhysicalNamingStrategy):

> `JPA` defines no separation between logical and physical name.
> Following the `JPA` specification, the logical name **is** the
> physical name. If `JPA` provider portability is important,
> applications should prefer not to specify a `PhysicalNamingStrategy`.

#### Further Reading

- [*Naming Strategies*](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#naming) in Hibernate User Guide